# how to put text in while just once php

Tags: php, fancybox, image-gallery

I have a fancy-box image gallery with a border and each image has if even border-top if odd border-bottom, like this:

[image]

And where is the thickest border it is supposed to be text.

I have this code to every picture in the image

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gibellino");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from imper");
     
 $first = 'first';
     
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $img = $row['img'];
  echo "<a href='imagem/bd/imper/$img' rel='imper' title='$img'><img src='imagem/bd/imper/$img' alt='' id='$first'><span></span></a>";
  $first = '';
 }
 echo "<h4>Impermeabilização</h4>";
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

All the images come from the database. But as you can see there is no text and I don't know what's the problem. Has anyone worked with fancybox? And had this problem?

Comment: view your HTML source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fetching the text from the same database you're getting the `$img` from, you can also include the text associated with your image within the `while` loop. Like this...

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gibellino");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from imper");
     
 $first = 'first';
     
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $img = $row['img'];
  echo "<a href='imagem/bd/imper/$img' rel='imper' title='$img'><img src='imagem/bd/imper/$img' alt='' id='$first'><span>$some_text</span></a>";
  $first = '';
 }
 echo "<h4>Impermeabilização</h4>";
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: the text doesn't come from the database. Who writes it is me